# How to write a web server (service) in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I wish to write a web service server (using http protocol) in OCaml.

For a simple example, I want to write a `http server`. User can access it and provide parameter like `http://myservice.com?i=1&j=2`. Then my server get the request and parameters and `calculate i+j` and return the result.

---

Of course, my service will be more complicated for the calculation part. Instead of this simple example of calculation, what I really need to do is to

1. access the database (MongoDB) to get some data
2. access another 3rd party web service to get more data
3. calculate all data to get a result and return to the user.

So, I also need to consider `parallelism` / `multi-threading`, although I want to start with simple case first.

---

My questions are:

- Which library should I use to first set up such a `http server`? I have looked into **Ocamlnet 3** and think it might be a good candidate, but it lacks good tutorial and I still don't know how to use `nethttpd` or `netplex` etc.
- How should I design the **architecture** of my web application? I know OCaml is not good at `parallelism`, then how can I make each service instance not blocking?

Comment: Hi I realise this is a very old question, but for people looking for an answer now,
You will find all mature http-related projects on [the related ocamlverse page](https://ocamlverse.github.io/content/web_networking.html). In particular, all modern http servers are built on top of `async` or `lwt`, which means you get nonblocking io.